# SourceTree Installation Fail on Windows 10: "CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: "

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree, appdata

I am trying to install SourceTree to my brand new Acer Laptop just arrived, the moment I run the installer downloaded from Atlassian "SourceTreeSetup-2.1.11.0",  it flashed for a second then pop up error message:

[image]

This is the full setup error log:

```
2017-09-02 11:11:32> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install . --rerunningWithoutUAC
2017-09-02 11:11:32> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2017-09-02 11:11:32> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree
2017-09-02 11:11:32> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\packages\.betaId'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.getOrCreateStagedUserId()
2017-09-02 11:11:32> CheckForUpdateImpl: Failed to load local releases, starting from scratch: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\packages\RELEASES'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Squirrel.Utility.LoadLocalReleases(String localReleaseFile)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.<CheckForUpdate>d__2.MoveNext()
2017-09-02 11:11:32> CheckForUpdateImpl: Reading RELEASES file from C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2017-09-02 11:11:32> CheckForUpdateImpl: First run or local directory is corrupt, starting from scratch
2017-09-02 11:11:32> ApplyReleasesImpl: Writing files to app directory: C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.1.11
2017-09-02 11:11:36> LogHost: Rigging execution stub for SourceTree_ExecutionStub.exe to C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\SourceTree.exe
2017-09-02 11:11:38> ApplyReleasesImpl: Squirrel Enabled Apps: [C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.1.11\SourceTree.exe]
2017-09-02 11:11:41> ApplyReleasesImpl: Starting fixPinnedExecutables
2017-09-02 11:11:41> ApplyReleasesImpl: Examining Pin: File Explorer.lnk
2017-09-02 11:11:41> ApplyReleasesImpl: Examining Pin: Google Chrome.lnk
2017-09-02 11:11:41> ApplyReleasesImpl: Fixing up tray icons
2017-09-02 11:11:41> ApplyReleasesImpl: Couldn't rewrite shim RegKey, most likely no apps are shimmed: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.<unshimOurselves>b__13_0(RegistryView view)
2017-09-02 11:11:41> ApplyReleasesImpl: Couldn't rewrite shim RegKey, most likely no apps are shimmed: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.<unshimOurselves>b__13_0(RegistryView view)
2017-09-02 11:11:41> ApplyReleasesImpl: cleanDeadVersions: for version 2.1.11
2017-09-02 11:11:41> ApplyReleasesImpl: cleanDeadVersions: exclude folder app-2.1.11
2017-09-02 14:10:34> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install . --rerunningWithoutUAC
2017-09-02 14:10:34> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2017-09-02 14:10:34> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree
2017-09-02 14:10:34> Program: Install path C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree already exists, burning it to the ground
2017-09-02 14:10:34> IEnableLogger: Failed to remove existing directory on full install, is the app still running???: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.1.11\tools\putty\plink.exe' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.SetAttributes(String path, FileAttributes fileAttributes)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<DeleteDirectory>b__19_0(String file)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.<ForEachAsync>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<LogIfThrows>d__42.MoveNext()
2017-09-02 14:10:34> Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.1.11\tools\putty\plink.exe' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.SetAttributes(String path, FileAttributes fileAttributes)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<DeleteDirectory>b__19_0(String file)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.<ForEachAsync>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<LogIfThrows>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.<Install>d__4.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.1.11\tools\putty\plink.exe' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.SetAttributes(String path, FileAttributes fileAttributes)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<DeleteDirectory>b__19_0(String file)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.<ForEachAsync>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Utility.<LogIfThrows>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.<Install>d__4.MoveNext()<---
```

Anyone happen to know solution for this issue ??

Comment: **"Failed to remove existing directory on full install, is the app still running???: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\blackhatSolo\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.1.11\tools\putty\plink.exe' is denied."** so stop the plink.exe in process explorer/task manager and other tools that prevent uninstall. also look at the security settings of this folder, so that your account has full permissions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have resolved my issue thus providing the solution for my own issue:

Since Windows 10, applications by default cannot access to `c:/user/[username]/AppData/` because the owner of that directory is belong to TrustedInstaller, I just spent 1/2 hr to solve this Windows 10 configuration by **changing the owner of this directory and its sub-directories** to myself.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried Edward Sun suggestion above - did not work - it's not about folder permissions.

This error occurs during app installations when the installer tried to update Sourcetree, probably to pull the new Git commit for this app.

A process can lock `c:/user/[username]/AppData/Local/[relevant app dir]` for some unclear reason. Tracking down the locking process is futile.

Workaround:

1. Restart windows 10 (normal restart. if it does not work, try Safe Mode restart).
2. Remove `c:/user/[username]/AppData/Local/[relevant app dir]`
3. Run the installer for the app.

During the restart, the directory seems to be released again and the installer can write to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the setup.exe file from PowerShell as administrator. It will resolve.

Answer (score 2):

When I tried install slack application I got similar error. I resolved of one via disabling antivirus on moment installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue here, and i just updated the security information in the folder.

```
2018-07-03 15:20:47> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
2018-07-03 15:20:47> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2018-07-03 15:20:47> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop
2018-07-03 15:20:47> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\packages\.betaId'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.getOrCreateStagedUserId()
```

To change the properties in this case we follow the folder impacted ->

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop

Then right click in the folder of "GitHubDesktop" and follow the below Steps:

1. Right click on the file or directory.
2. Click on “Properties” on the right click menu.
3. Click on “Security” tab.
4. Click on “Advanced” button at the bottom.
5. In Advanced Security Dialog window, check “Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object”
6. Click on Apply.
7. Click on "Ok", and you will see a popup with a windows process where the modifications will be applied for the current folder.
8. Click on "OK", and you already completed the process.

This is following the suggestion of "Edward Sun" and is in order to have a guide of the steps what i follow to solve the issue.

Thanks, Edward!

Answer (score -1):

Might also happen with your antivirus software.
I had to disable MalwareBytes Antimalware in order to use `takeown / SquirrelTemp /R` and then delete the folder.